# how to substract from default variable in perl

Tags: perl

This is probably something very basic, but I couldn't find an answer to this elsewhere:

it seems in an interation over an array I can add to a default variable to target other items in the array but I cannot substract from it, like so:

```
foreach (0..$#array) {
    if ( $array[$_] =~ m/PATTERN/ ) {
        $array[$_] = $TRING1;
        $array[$_+1] = $TRING2;
        $array[$_-1] = $TRING3;
    };
};
```

It just doesn't assign anything to the previous item but leaves it as it was (I never get <0).

I'm probably missing something trivial here?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Could you post a small script that is runnable and reproduces your issue?

Comment: `STRING1`, `STRING2`, and `STRING3` are barewords.  Make sure to always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Every. Single. Time.

Comment: @JackManey I do use strict and warnings. The barewords were only here to say "some string". I'm sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: @jcm - Fair enough.  Thanks for the clarification.  A couple of possibly unintended consequences that your code might have: 1. On the first step (`$_==0`), you might be changing the last element of `@array`.  2. A particular element of the array may end up getting changed more than once, depending on what your pattern is.

Comment: You should be aware that `$array[$_-1]` can become `$array[-1]`, which refers to the last element in the list.

Comment: As demonstrated above and in tanget's answer, your code is unreliable. You are probably asking [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45154/13917). You would get a better answer if you were to describe what you are trying to accomplish with this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be changing the elements in your array at the same time as you are iterating over them and checking for a pattern. If you put a print statement in you will see:

```
my @array = qw/PATTERN PATTERN PATTERN/;
my ($str1,$str2,$str3) = qw/A B C/;
foreach (0..$#array) {
    print qq|Index is $_, pattern is $array[$_]\n|;
    if ( $array[$_] =~ m/PATTERN/ ) {
        $array[$_]      = $str1;
        $array[$_+1]    = $str2;
        $array[$_-1]    = $str3;
    };
};

Prints:
Index is 0, pattern is PATTERN
Index is 1, pattern is B
Index is 2, pattern is C
```

Creating a new array will help but it's still an unpredictable construct as far as I can see.